# Join statement error in CodeIgniter 2.x

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to join 2 tables in a database but i am finding an error which is like

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Hostel\application\models\studentaccounts.php on line
>   37

my model code is as follows

```
$query=$this->db->select('*')
        ->from('student')   
        ->join('securitybill','securitybill.student_id'='student.student_id','inner')
                 ->get();   
        return $query->result();
```

I have check out the documentation it states the code similar to it but i am still facing the issue...can you tell me what is the issue with my code?

Comment: `'securitybill.student_id'='student.student_id'` <-- incorrect

Comment: 'securitybill.student_id=student.student_id'

Comment: Try like this `'securitybill.student_id = student.student_id'`

Comment: Change your join statement 
    from :-  'securitybill.student_id'='student.student_id'
    to   :-     'securitybill.student_id=student.student_id'